Допустимо ли использовать при деплое встроенный сервер разработки Django в локальной сети?
Есть локальная сеть на 30 рабочих мест, без выхода в интернет. Есть веб приложение на Django, чтобы не мучаться с nginx, uwsgi и т.п. допустимо ли использовать встроенный сервер разработки? Знаю, что в инструкции к django написано в продакшн его не использовать, но если клиентов в сети не больше 30 будет, то повлияет ли это на производительность? Одновременный доступ к приложению нескольких пользователей? И какие ещё могут быть ограничения?
Использование веб приложения планируется в долгосрочной перспективе.

Во-первых, речь не только про производительность, но и про безопасность — никто не заморачивается с тем, чтобы встроенный сервер нельзя было взломать (и вообще в нём инструменты отладки есть). Во-вторых, а зачем, если можно просто нормальный сервер поставить?

Потому что нормальный сервер для django приложения разворачивать опыта не было, а со встроенным проще и в моих условиях подумал, вдруг этого хватит. Плюс интернета в локальной сети нет, развернуть уже сложнее...думаю будет ли работать метод, если я разверну сервер дома в виртуальной машине с интернетом и перенесу эту виртуальную машину в локальную сеть, где интернета нет?

Ничто не мешает развернуть нормальный сервер без интернета, непонятно зачем с виртуальной машиной извращаться (ну можно конечно, но зачем)
